# Laravel validation returns null

Tags: php, laravel, validation, null

As the title says, my validation in Laravel 5.5 is not working, this is the code in my controller

```
$val = $this->validate($request, [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email'
                ]);
                if($val->fails()) {
                    return "Fail":
                } else {
                    return "Success";
                }
```

if I try to dump the variable `$val` I get `null` in return. Also I've checked if I get my input correctly, and yes, `$request->input()` returns my data.

fields in the request:

```
"name" => "test"
  "email" => "test@test.com"
  "oldPassword" => null
  "newPassword" => null
  "repeatPassword" => null
```

(the null fields are not validated cause I don't need them in this request so they're null)

It's been a while since I've touched Laravel but I remember always using this for validation, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`validate()` does not return anything.  It simply throws a `400 Bad Request` error if it fails, along with a message containing the reason for failure (ie. "First name field is required").  The fact you are getting past it means the data is valid.

If you want to use your own logic like this you could do something like:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'name' => 'required',
      'email' => 'required|email'
]);

if($validator->fails()){
    $errors = $validator->errors();
    ....
```

Comment: Thanks, I supposed I could use the documentation's validate, but I didn't know how it worked. \Validator seems working fine.

Comment: Actually @Jeff, the validate method returns an array. I'm surprised how the OP's dump of the output is null. It definitely isn't a Validator object but it is an array. Check out https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Validation/ValidatesRequests.html#method_validate

Comment: @Paras ah.  Not sure why it is null in that case.  But I did trace the `validate()` function back to the `Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validate()` method which does throw an error if it fails.  So there would be no return in that case.